# Программа на Python, что выводит количество чисел в строке

Tags: python, unicode, print

Пользователь вводит строку произвольной длины.
Программа выводит количество чисел в этой строке.
Если чисел нет, программа выводит "числа не обнаружены".
В выводимой строке все буквы строчные

```
line=input("").split()
cnt=0
for i,s in enumerate(line):
    if s.isdigit():
        cnt+= len(s) # считаем цифры
if cnt == 0:
    print("числа не обнаружены")
else:
    print("",cnt)
```

Выводит количество чисел, только когда чисел нет, выдает ошибку вместо "числа не обнаружены".Что сделать, чтобы выводилось "числа не обнаружены" при их отсутствии?

Comment: В вопросе Вы говорите про числа, а в коде комментарий про подсчёт цифр. Так что нужно? Приведите пример входных-выходных данных, так будет проще.

Comment: А у меня ваш код работает. Правда я писал no - на английском

Comment: Какую ошибку выводит - секрет?

Comment: от такую: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..\Playground\", line 7, in <module>
    print("\u0447\u0438\u0441\u043b\u0430 \u043d\u0435 \u043e\u0431\u043d\u0430\u0440\u0443\u0436\u0435\u043d\u044b")
  File "..\Playground\", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Переделать код Python, чтобы программа выводила количество ЧИСЕЛ из строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1020549/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-python-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%a7%d0%98%d0%a1%d0%95%d0%9b-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2):

Вот так получилось:

```py
import re

s = input("Введите строку: ")
count = len(re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', s))

print(count, ' числа') if count else print('числа не обнаружены')
```

Вывод:

> Введите строку: абв 123 где 456 xyz89
> 2  числа

Comment: Автор уточнил - _Стоит сделать чтобы считало количество ЧИСЕЛ_, правда почему то не в самом вопросе, а в ответе.

Comment: Переделал на числа, но такой ответ уже есть. Я и ответил, потому что думал, другой ошибся. И что делать?

Comment: Непонятно, что считается числом. Возможно, тут 0 или 1 должен быть ответ `x00100q000`. Чтобы ответ не совпадал с другим, можете усложнить регулярку с условиями разделения пробелами или/и недопустимыми числами с начальными нулями. <кстати, чтобы участник получил уведомление поставьте собаку + его ник перед сообщением @0xdb>

Comment: @dIm0n Вот переделал, так?

Answer (score 1):

```
line = input("вводит строку: ")
# вводит строку: Программа1 выводит 2 количество 3 чисел в 4этой строке

cnt = sum([ 1 for s in line if s.isdigit() ])

print("числа не обнаружены" if not cnt else "обнаруженo чисел {} ".format(cnt))
обнаруженo чисел 4
```

Comment: Расскажете, почему именно `sum([1 for s...])`? Есть какой-то выигрыш в производительности?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в кодировке и в том, что в файле есть текст на русском языке.

Добавь самой первой строкой в скрипт

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line=input()
digit_counter = 0
for i in line:
    if i.isdigit():
        digit_counter+=1
if digit_counter == 0:
    print("числа не обнаружены")
else:
    print(digit_counter)
```

Comment: line=input()
digit_counter = 0
for i in line:
    if i.isdigit():
        digit_counter+=1
if digit_counter == 0:
    print("числа не обнаружены")
else:
    print(digit_counter) Выводит количество чисел из строки, если пользователь вводит числа через пробел. В том случае, когда вводит пользователь буквы - выдает ошибку. Вместо "числа не обнаружены"

Comment: вы задачу нормально сформулируйте. Вам что надо то - посчитать все числа из введенных вперемешку символов и чисел или считать числа до тех пор, пока ни введется символ?

Answer (score 0):

Приблизительно как то так:

```
sheridan@spc /tmp $ cat ./test.py   
line=input("")
cnt=0
for s in line:
    if s.isdigit():
        cnt+=1
if cnt:
    print(cnt)
else:
    print("числа не обнаружены")
sheridan@spc /tmp $ python ./test.py
12345
5
sheridan@spc /tmp $ python ./test.py
qwerty
числа не обнаружены
sheridan@spc /tmp $ python ./test.py
1q2w3e4r
4
```

Comment: Код выше работает, только нужно при чтобы считало числа, а не цифры

Comment: line=input("")
cnt=0
for s in line:
    if s.isdigit():
        cnt+=1
if cnt:
    print(cnt)
else:
    print("числа не обнаружены") Стоит сделать чтобы считало количество  ЧИСЕЛ, а не цифры. А в случае если вводимой строке например"uihgyug" нет чисел то выводило на экран "числа не обнаружены"

Answer (score 0):

```
line=input("").split()
```

(возможно писать тоже как `line=input().split()`). Вы разбили введенную строку на *список слов*.

```
for i,s in enumerate(line):
```

Не нужно так сделать — переменную `i` вы не используете. Достаточно `for s in line:`

```
if s.isdigit():
```

Правильно. Возвращает `True` тогда (и только тогда), когда все символы в слове `s` являются цифрами.

```
    cnt+= len(s) # считаем цифры
```

**Нет!** Задача была считать **числа** (как 3158), а не *отдельные цифры* (как 3, 1, 5, 8). Исправите на

```
    cnt += 1     # считаем числа
```

Ваш остальной код в порядке, только почему вместо чудесного (хотя правильного) `print("",cnt)` не писать просто `print(cnt)`?

Comment: Все понятно, только чем заменить строку if s.isdigit(): чтобы при отсутствии вводимых чисел выводилась на экран фраза "числа не обнаружены" вместо "False"  error и огромного кода с подробностями ошибки?)

Comment: Ничего заменить не надо, программа работает правильно, при отсутствии чисел выводит текст "числа не обнаружены" - я тестировал ее.

Comment: Когда тестирую на sololearn выдает ошибку при вводе только букв. от такой код, за вашими рекомендациями `line=input("")
cnt=0
for s in line:
    if s.isdigit():
        cnt+=1
if cnt:
    print(cnt)
else:
    print("числа не обнаружены")`

Comment: У меня нет возможности тестирования кода на SoloLearn (и не хочу, потому что это нет стандартная среда для Питон). Важно, что ваша программа работает (и работала) в стандартном Питоне — не было ни какой ошибки.

Comment: @Koviedesigner, не стоит. (Когда мой ответ + комментарии вам помогли, почему не нажать на галочку и / или на стрелку вверх у него?)

Answer (score 0):

@moffire Вот готовый код

Стоит сделать чтобы считало количество  ЧИСЕЛ, а не цифры. А в случае если вводимой строке например"uihgyug" нет чисел то выводило на экран "числа не обнаружены"

```
line=input("")
cnt=0
for s in line:
    if s.isdigit():
        cnt+=1
if cnt:
    print(cnt)
else:
    print("числа не обнаружены")
```

Answer (score 0):

Почему просто не использовать регулярные выражения?

```
import re

string = input("Введите строку ")
cnt = len(re.findall('\d+',string))
if cnt:
    print(cnt)
else:
    print('Числа не обнаружены')
```