# Переделать код Python, чтобы программа выводила количество ЧИСЕЛ из строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, if, print

Нужно,чтобы программа выводила количество ЧИСЕЛ из строки, что ввел пользователь. 
Если ЧИСЕЛ нет, на экране выводилось "числа не обнаружены".

У меня при запуске кода и вводе cтроки "45енп67" Output: 4  А чисел то 2.
В случае, если введу любую строку без чисел, например "нниирл", было "числа не обнаружены" а не ошибка и куча кода.

Возможно дело в кодировке и строке  `if s.isdigit()`:

```py
line=input("")
cnt=0
for s in line:
    if s.isdigit():
        cnt+=1
if cnt:
    print(cnt)
else:
    print("числа не обнаружены")
```

Comment: @Эникейщик хоть это и про одну задачу, а вопросы таки разные

Comment: В этом вопросе я вижу два вопроса - про числа и кодировку. @andreymal

Comment: согласен с @Эникейщик, что дубль

Comment: Задание такое  #Пользователь вводит строку произвольной длины.
#Программа выводит количество чисел в этой строке.
#Если чисел нет, программа выводит "числа не обнаружены" .
#Обратите внимание, что в выводимой строке все буквы строчные

Answer (score 7):

Используйте регулярные выражения.

```
import re 
a = "45енп67"

print(len(re.findall(r'\d+', a)))
```

> 2

Или, более развернуто:

```
import re 

a = "45енп67"

res = len(re.findall(r'\d+', a))

if res:
    print(res)
else:
    print("числа не обнаружены")
```

Comment: Куда именно в моем коде вставить import re? Обьясните пожалуйста начинающему программисту?

Comment: @Koviedesigner импортирование модулей производится в самом начале скрипта, в его первых строчках, как сказано в PEP8: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

Comment: Задание такое #Пользователь вводит строку произвольной длины. #Программа выводит количество чисел в этой строке. #Если чисел нет, программа выводит "числа не обнаружены" . #Обратите внимание, что в выводимой строке все буквы строчные